# eclipse debug window encoding?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm currently trying to debug a php web application with eclipse luna pdt.
Everything's find except I can't read variable names (written in korean) during the debugging

[Please see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6c4H.png)

korean variable names reads fine on "outline" section (b), but has problem displaying them in "Variables" section (a).
It seems that it's relevant to encoding configuration or so, but I can't find 
where to fix this. Please help!

fyi, I'm using xdebug for debugging php and installed "makegood" plugin (for using korean variable name... eclipse won't let me use korean variable name by default, as you know)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : go to your Eclipse install directory, edit the `eclipse.ini` file, scroll to the bottom of the file which are all the `-vmargs` arguments on separate lines, and add:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

on its own line, then restart Eclipse. Now the host VM running Eclipse will be operating with the UTF-8 encoding and the UI elements in the interface will be able to display those values.

Comment: Hi @flafoux, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but had no effect.